# jQuery Retrieve ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried tackling my first project, an accordion menu. I have set to each item that needs to show/hide a class of .menu and an id.

While trying to retrieve the id's of each element i've used this statement:

```
var $currentId = $('ul.menu').attr('id');
```

Only problem is that it seems this only retrieves the id of the first element. Can anyone tell how can I retrieve all the It's to store them in a variable. I am planing to use if statements in order to check  for each particular id when it's clicked.Thank You!

EDIT:It seems I was misunderstood what I have to do is this I'll start from the beginning:

Here is my HTML :

```
<ul id="container">
    <li class="select"><a href ="#">Downloads</a></li>

    <li >
        <ul class = "menu" id="first" >
            <li>
                <a href ="#">iTunes</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href ="#">iTunes</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="select">
        <a href ="#">Products List  </a>
    </li>
     <li>
         <ul class = "menu" id="second"  >
            <li>
                <a href ="#">iTunes</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href ="#">iTunes</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

What I have to do is when I click on the li with class of select I have to make the ul with the class of menu appear. How I wanted to do this to retrieve all the id's of the ul.menu and store them in a variable and when I click on any of the li.select the underlying ul should show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `each` loop to get the ids of each element. Inside the loop use just just use `this.id` to get the id of the element where `this represents the dom element.

```
$('ul.menu').each(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

If you want the ids of all elements into an array you can use jQuery `map` method.

```
var Ids = $.map($('ul.menu'), function(){
              return this.id;
          });
```

`map()` translates all items in an array or object to new array of items. `Ids` will contain the ids of all the elements.

Then you can use `$.inArray` to search for a specific id within it. It will return its index or -1 if not found in the array.

```
if($.inArray("someId", Ids) != -1){
    //Id found in the array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to iterate over all the items and check the current status.

You can do this using the [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

You can even dynamically add a listener for the click event for each element that matches your selector (in this case 'ul.menu'):

```
$('ul.menu').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function()
      {
         alert('click');
      });
});
```

EDIT: You can do this to hide/show the secondary items when the li.select items are clicked:

```
$('li.select').click(function(){
      $(this).next().toggle();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an array that contains the ids:

```
var listOfIds = [];
$('ul.menu').each(function(){ listOfIds.push(this.id); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The better thing to do would be to use

```
$('ul.menu li').click(function(event){
$(this).attr('id');
});
```

That will setup an event listener for each menu item and then allow you to do some thing when that menu item is clicked. The line with $(this).attr('id') can be replaced with any code you wish. Maybe even $(this).find('ul').show();

Comment: `this.id` > `$(this)[0].id` > `$(this).prop('id')` > `$(this).attr('id')`.